# Vlookup only pulling in first instance of duplicate

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Hi I have a column with our portfolio strategies and a column with the NAV for those strategies. I want to pull those values into a summary tab. However, sometimes a strategy may appear twice in the table array because part of the portfolio may be asset backed and part may be receivables backed etc. so we account for them separately. When I used vlookup to pull in the values it only pulls in the first instance of the name ignoring the second. Adding a unique identifier to the end of the second instance is not an option.

I am using the following udf but it's not exactly working. What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Function CustomVLookUp(VL, Table As Range, Col, Inst)
On Error GoTo x

Set SearchCol = Table.Columns(1)

If Abs(Int(Inst)) <> Inst Or Inst > _
Application.CountIf(SearchCol, VL) Or Inst = 0 Then GoTo x

Set mtch = SearchCol.Find(VL, LookIn:=xlValues)
For i = 1 To (Inst - 1)
    Set mtch = SearchCol.Find(VL, After:=mtch, LookIn:=xlValues)
Next

CustomVLookUp = mtch.Offset(0, Col - 1).Value

Exit Function

x:  CustomVLookUp = ""
End Function
```

Comment: If you want to add all of the numbers together, you need a sumifs

Comment: I'd suggest you mock up the table it's looking at and what you'd expect to get back so we can see what you're after. The code itself looks good to me, as it's only designed to return 1 match, you just get to specify which one.

Comment: So the names are in column q and the results are in column r.

Comment: You want the total of column R where the name in Q matches VL?

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm looking for.